# How to configure a standalone nginx reverse proxy server to handle SSL traffic to separte machines running wordpress on apache?

Tags: linux, nginx, apache2

How do I create a secure connection to my apache 2 websites?

[image]

```
revProxy server xyz.com.conf
# Redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  xyz.com www.xyz.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# For ssl
server {
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xyz.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/xyz.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDH$';
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000";

    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    listen 443;
    server_name  xyz.com www.xyz.com;

    root /var/www/xyz.com;

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.4;
    }
}
```

This nginx server block is not secure. How do I create secure connections to both wordpress sites?

Comment: I don't know what happened to my network diagram. Reverse nginx proxy server at 192.168.1.7. It handles security certificates and routes http/https traffic to the correct  Apache website server running wordpress PHP at 192.168.1.4. The above server block allows access to the website but it is not secure.

Comment: (1) your image ref didn't work because you indented it, making it part of the  'code' block not text; fixed (minimally). Although that ASCII-art diagram is simple enough you could inline it as another code block here, and save people the time following the link. (2) what exactly do you mean by 'not secure'? Connections to your proxy (I assume forwarded from your gateway) are redirected to HTTPS with parameters that are at least superficially reasonable. Do you mean your LAN-only backend connection? If you want to use HTTPS there, specify HTTPS in `proxy_pass`.

Comment: (3) if you want to renew your cert using this nginx (not e.g. standalone or DNS-01) the `.well-known` exception must be for HTTP (80) not HTTPS (443). See the LE website.